# How to insert variable to x_path?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

My code that doesn't work

```
size_id = "'739'"

path = '"//div[@data-option-value-id=' + size_id + ']"'

driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
```

working code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-option-value-id='739']").click()
```

realy don't know how to fix. I use variauble because it requires different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close just confuse the quotation.Try below code.

```
size_id = "739"
path = "//div[@data-option-value-id='" + size_id + "']"

driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
```

Or you can use format function which is much easier.

```
size_id = "739"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-option-value-id='{}']".format(size_id)).click()
```

Comment: ty so much, what .format actually do? Returns variable {here} ?

Comment: Yes you are spot on.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are python 3.x, f-strings are your best friends:

```
path = f'//div[@data-option-value-id="{size_id}"]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
```

Your mistake was that you didn't enclose the `size_id` into `"`.

`path = '//div[@data-option-value-id="' + size_id + '"]'` could work too.